# Help Icons is not showing in SP 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, file-icons

I'm confused why the icons (ex. setting and help) are missing?

[image]

Comment: Please check your internet connection, it happens with us when we are not using Proxy to connect to Internet from Our Organization

Answer (score 0):

Some Logos in SharePoint are represented using downloaded fonts. Windows 10 has a new Group-Policy Setting `Untrusted Font Blocking`. Someone in your organization [might have enabled this via GPO](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/block-untrusted-fonts-in-enterprise) as Microsoft recommended some time ago. This setting  will break downloaded fonts in SharePoint 2016.

In 2017 Microsoft [reversed this recommendation](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/secguide/2017/06/15/dropping-the-untrusted-font-blocking-setting/). The current recommendation is to `Disable` this setting.

[image: GPO]